# Как стилизовать кнопки социальных сетей с помощью БЭМ модификаторов?

Tags: html, css, бэм

Допустим есть такой HTML для соц. сетей

```
       <ul class="social">
          <li class="social__item">
            <a class="social__link social__link--vk" href="#">Вконтакте</a>
          </li>
          <li class="social__item">
            <a class="social__link social__link--inst"href="#">Инстаграм</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

и CSS

```
.social {
  font-size: 0;
}
.social__link {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.social__link::before {
  content: "";
}
```

Как сделать чтобы БЭМ модификатор `social__link--vk` для before добавлял background-image с иконкой вк, шириной, высотой, `social__link--inst` иконку инстаграма и ее высоту ширину?
Просто совсем не понимаю, как это делается с помощью БЭМа...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.social__link::before {
  content: "";
  background-size: 100%;
}

.social__link--vk:before {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-image: url();
}

.social__link--inst:before {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-image: url();
}
```